# Azure Data Studio Database Project - Unable to Build

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-studio

I have a new install of Azure Data Studio with SQL Database Projects, SQL Server Dacpac and SQL Server Schema Compare extentions.

I created a database project from an existing database (AdventureWorks2019) installed on SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition.

When I select 'Build' I get the following error

Build Failed.
error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages

I get this same issue from creating a blank project, or from several other databases I have tried.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this by editing the nuget.config file located at: C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config.

You can add the following within the packagesSources element:

```
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you very much - that did it!